# mp4 content won't play in webpages served to Samsung Internet browser

Tags: cross-browser, html5-video, mp4, mpeg-dash

I have a website which is able to play mp4 media (via the `<video>` tag and via DASH) in every browser except the Samsung Internet browser, which comes as default on Samsung Galaxy phones and probably a lot of other Samsung devices.

On a desktop, iPad, or even an ancient HP TouchPad tablet, it works fine.  Using other browsers on the same Samsung device (e.g. Chrome), the mp4 media plays fine, so it's not a limitation of Android or the device hardware.

I can detect the Samsung browser with JavaScript and disable video content on those devices, but I'd really like to not have to do that.  Surely there is a workaround.

Here's a quick test, if you'd like to try it on your device.  It tries to play 3 slightly different types of mp4 media on one page:

http://2pic.me/dashtest.html

On my Samsung Galaxy S6, none of them play in the Samsung Internet browser.

I tried using video.js, but that did not change the behavior.

**Update**:

In the year since I posted this, Samsung has finally updated their browser, and mp4 content now plays correctly, including auto-play.

Comment: Is BLOB of a video supported by Samsung Internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the same issue on Samsung Browser (current latest: v6.2.01.12), on a Samsung Galaxy 7 device. In my case I was using video.js, and playing HLS.
The problem I found was that autoplay was not working.
My solution was to try to play the video programatically and if failure detected (promise rejection), then display a PLAY button, and play the video in the user click. That worked for me.
It would be something like:

```
const video = document.getElementById('my-video');
video.play()
  .catch((err) => {
    if (err.name === 'NotAllowedError') {
      // Display PLAY button with a click event listener and play the video there.
    }
  });
```

This is a simplified code, I do specific checks to see if my-video is an actual `<video>` element, and if `video.play()` returns a promise and all the basic safe checks (since this is supported in many other browsers).
But, it shows the idea to handle this autoplay not working scenario.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Wow, this is a very helpful insight!  Every video on my site is autoplay with no controls, so it never occurred to me to try to show controls or to play manually via JS.  I had always assumed it was a codec limitation in that browser.

Comment: The play() call does fail on the Samsung browser, but at least I have some sort of solution here in the form of activating the controls (which do function).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Samsung's mobile browser does not appear to support HTML5 Media Source Extensions (MSE) at the time - these are required for DASH playback.

You can test for MSE support on a browser using several online links, such as:

- https://bitmovin.com/browser-capabilities/

Comment: I'm very confused, because https://caniuse.com/#feat=mediasource seems to imply that Samsung's browser does support MSE since 5.0 (I'm using 6.2), and that Safari on iOS does not support MSE.  I've found the exact opposite to be true in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me fine, you can use mute if more than one video need to play check this:

```
<pre>
  <video class="video" webkit-playsinline="" playsinline="" muted="" autoplay="" loop="" preload="auto" width="100%" height="auto" controles=""> 
    <source src="wp-content/uploads/talkforweb.com.au.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</pre>
```

Comment: It appears that Samsung has finally gotten with the times and updated their browser since my question was originally posted.