# Use Play() method to start dynamically loaded HTML 5 Video in IOS Safari / Chrome Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a jQuery onclick function to dynamically load in an HTML5 video player, which I'm then trying to call `play()` on to make it play as soon as it appears.

This works fine on desktop chrome / safari, but not on their mobile counterparts. I'm aware that mobile browsers (Safari in particular) are understandably funny about the play() method, but I was under the impression that calling it from a user interaction event (such as a click) was ok?

Perhaps it is the fact the the video is being dynamically loaded in the same interaction function? Has anyone else experienced this / can suggest a workaround or let me know that I'm doing something wrong.

The jQuery function goes something like this:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#vidloader', function( event ){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/get_video.html?id=123',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {       

            $("#dynamicVideoHolder").append('<div class="dynVidViewer">' + data + '</div>');

            construct_video_player( 'dynVidViewer' );

            var newvideo = document.getElementById("newvid");
            newvideo.play();

        }
    });     

    return false;

});
```

get_video.html loads a pre-constructed `<video>` (id='newvid') element and supporting UI, construct_video_player creates supporting interaction around the UI. All works fine, just won't play as soon as it's loaded!

Comment: try with audiomuted see https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are calling `play()` in the callback of the ajax call, so the context is lost, and it doesn't count as a user interaction anymore.

Try to log what is happening with:

```
newvideo.play()
  .then(() => console.log('success :)'))
  .catch(err => console.log('error :( ', err));
```

If my guess is correct, the execution should go to the catch, and you should see something like `NotAllowedError`.

So... you are going to need to move that `play()` out of the ajax callback.
A workaround would be to let the `play()` call as it is (since works on desktop browsers), and just show a play button if the initial `play()` call fails (that would be the case of some mobile devices), then you will need another "click" event on that play button, that will play again the video, now without any ajax call involved. There is an example of this in another answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47683977/4067893).

I hope it helps!

Comment: Ah ok - I totally hadn't considered the context side of things... I tried your code and it caught the error "DOMException: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture.". I think I may have come up with a way around it though based on what you said - I set a global 'videoIsLoaded' variable to false, which I set to true in the callback function of the ajax call. Then I use setInterval to create a function to watch when that turns true which then calls the play() method. Not as clean as i'd like, but hey seems to work :) Many thanks for your help, I wouldn't have worked it out otherwise.

Comment: Sweet! Great to read that it worked!
 I was a bit surprised it worked, though, since you have the `play()` inside the function of the setInterval, so I thought the context would be lost as well.
BUT... I found out that a user gesture is forwarded on `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. (You learn something new every day!), with some restrictions, like  "if a setTimeout handler invokes setTimeout again, the user gesture won't be forwarded twice, and if the timeout is >1s it won't be forwarded either."
How much is your timeout? Less than 1s, right?

Comment: These couple of links helped me to understand it:
- https://github.com/WICG/interventions/issues/12
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=354217

Comment: Great finds on those links, it's a lot clearer now. Yeah it was more a trial and error than a deep understanding of context that got me there, but now it all makes a lot more sense. Yep I set the timeout at 100ms which ticks the box for the gesture forwarding and also makes it run quicker :) Thanks again!